# What would be the impact of changing or setting the SignInScheme when already deployed in production

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid, google-openid

Our authentication system is currently seeing many "Correlation failed" errors for some users trying to connect via Google Sign In. We're using Identity Server 4 / ASP.NET identity with .NET Core 2.2. Obviously, we can't reproduce.

Though we tried to understand every aspect of what we were implementing and deploying, the whole authentication flow and the many configuration possibilities of ASP.NET Identity and IS4 still hold mystery to us. We've tried to pinpoint the true cause of those "correlation failed" errors, but cannot be sure. We do have data protection in place that prevents issues with load balancing and multiple instances. We're almost certain it's not related to HTTP vs HTTPS. But foremost, it looks like this error is more frequent lately, though we don't see what change could have triggered this.

One thing we realized, and we're not sure of the impact, is that the Google authentication is configured without an explicit `SignInScheme`:

```
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    var section = Configuration.GetSection("ExternalLogin:Google");
                    options.ClientId = section.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
                    options.ClientSecret = section.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
                });
```

[Documentation about IS4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html#the-role-of-cookies) seems to indicate we should have set this in the first place:

```
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
```

On the other hand, articles [like this one](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) say that this scheme gets replaced by ASP.NET Identity.

> Because ASP.NET Identity also changes the default authentication scheme, any instances of `IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme` and `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme`, should be changed to `IdentityConstants.Application` and `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` respectively.

This just adds to our overall confusion, and we're not sure if it means changes to the external login callback as well.

Can we add that simple `SignInScheme` line to the Google options without impacting other users which still can connect with Google Sign In without any issue? Does it have a chance to fix the correlation errors we see? Otherwise, where should we look?